# After opening multiple pages with Puppeteer I get blank pages

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

I apologize if I duplicated the topic, but everything I've tried so far doesn't help.
I am trying to scraping some details data from each links from ads.
After opened few links, I get each next time blank page without any data.
Also, if I stop script and start it again I can't do it(because I received blank page on the start) and need to wait few minutes.
This is code and can you please said me where I made mistake.

Thank you :)

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
      "--disable-infobars",
      "--window-position=0,0",
      "--ignore-certifcate-errors",
      "--ignore-certifcate-errors-spki-list",
      '--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3312.0 Safari/537.36"',
    ],
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(
    "https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/s-immobilien/01309/c195l23973"
  );

  const banner = (await page.$("#gdpr-banner-accept")) !== null;

  if (banner) {
    await Promise.all([page.click("#gdpr-banner-accept")]);
  }
  let isBtnDisabled = false;
  while (!isBtnDisabled) {
    const productsHandles = await page.$$(".ad-listitem.lazyload-item");
    for (const producthandle of productsHandles) {
      try {
        link = await page.evaluate(
          (el) => el.querySelector("a.ellipsis").href,
          producthandle
        );

        const eachPage = await browser.newPage();
        await eachPage.goto(link, {
          waitUntil: "networkidle0",
        });
        await eachPage.waitForSelector("#viewad-price", {
          visible: true,
        });
        const price = await eachPage.$eval(
          "#viewad-price",
          (price) => price.textContent
        );
        console.log(price);
        eachPage.close();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }

    await page.waitForSelector("#srchrslt-pagination > div", { visible: true });
    const is_disabled =
      (await page.$(
        "#srchrslt-pagination > div > div.pagination-nav > .pagination-next"
      )) === null;

    isBtnDisabled = is_disabled;
    if (!is_disabled) {
      await Promise.all([
        page.click(".pagination-nav > .pagination-next"),
        page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle2" }),
      ]);
    }
  }

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: What data are you expecting to get?

Comment: Nothing special i need price, title, url, all this data not required login or something ...

Comment: Thanks -- could you [edit] the post to show the expected output? This makes it easier to answer.